# How to change a series name after creating the chart in excel using apple script.

Tags: excel, applescript

My next question is how to change the series name in this way.

1)

```
 tell application "Microsoft Excel"
         tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
            set obj to make new chart object at end with properties {name:"chart1",left position:20,   top:88,width:33, height:90}
            set ochart to chart of obj
            tell ochart
                set chart type to column clustered
                set newSeries to make new series at end with properties {series values:"=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$10", xvalues:"=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$10",name:"tempSeriesName"}
           end tell
         end tell
      end tell
```

2)

```
tell the chart of sheet "chart1"     
             tell series1       
                 set name to "chartseries1"                       
            end tell                 
     end tell
```

In this scripts, first script is run successfully but second script is not change the name of first series. 
Please reply I am waiting your replay.

Comment: It appears that your other two questions have been answered correctly. If so, accept them so other users know the questions are no longer open. If not, describe what issues you are still having so others may help you.

Comment: Hi , In the second script How to select the chart and return a chart object is ochart. which change the series name "tempSeriesName" to "chartseries1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set name of first series of chart of chart object 1 to "chartseries1"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, My second question is, how to set the chart element of chart. I am using this script                                               "set char element chart element 2"   this script through error.

Comment: Hi , I am waiting your replay.